# An inequality with simple and double integral of the same function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I would like some help in the following :

Let $\mu$ a prob measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

If I have $$\iint |x-y| d\mu(x)\mu(y) \geqslant 2a \int |x| d\mu(x) $$

for some $a>0$, can I deduce that $a=\infty$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. Consider $\mu$ to be the probability measure that assigns total mass 1 at the point zero. Then, both sides are zero.

Comment: what if the probability measure μ is Gaussian ? Can I deduce it then ?

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Gaussian with zero mean and unit variance. What you want to prove is $\mathbf{E}(|X - Y|)\geq a \mathbf{E}(|X|)$ implies $a = \infty.$ However, $Y$ and $-Y$ have the same law and booth are independent of $X,$ this shows $X - Y$ is normal with mean zero and variance $2.$ Then $\mathbf{E}(|X-Y|)$ is finite, so no. Not even then.